# Marketing Cloud Automations Failing - Transfer Activity - Eye Symbol

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, automationstudio, fileupload

We started experiencing a group of automations failing. Automations that hadn't failed in the past but for some reason began to fail upon the file transfer activity. When I look at the file transfer activity, an eye symbol is now appearing stating that other file activities may use this same location. I looked through SF documentation and didn't see anywhere this would be an issue.

I removed the dynamic attributes in the file transfer ask, and the transfer works, however when I revert back to the dynamic part of the file naming convention (year, month, day, minute, second) it fails. I'm stumped. Any thoughts? [image]
[image]

Comment: Typically, you'd use %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%% as the file name pattern on your File Transfer Activity for a File Drop Automation. Does that fix your issue?

Comment: That's the thing, we were originally utilizing %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%, but it began erroring out, even though it had run successfully before. Could it have something to do with the file location? The eye also appeared at the same time that it started erroring out, so that seems to be the source of the issue. I just don't know how it relates.

Comment: A bit of a long shot, but your file names are pretty long, if you're adding a datestamp to the end. Could you test reducing the side of that prefix that goes before your date to see if there's some sort of undocumented limitation on lengths of filenames, maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately @Macca we have automations with longer names that seem to work fine. Very strange overall.